# How to farm tall jungle trees?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a jungle tree farm, but all of the trees that grow are short and they're not producing any cocoa beans.

How can I farm tall jungle trees and cocoa?

Comment: What kind of fruit?  Are you talking [cocoa beans](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Cocoa_Bean) or [apples](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Apple)?

Comment: Yeah, and several things a don't remember their names.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie is there some way to merge these three questions?

Comment: @Ender The normal duplicate question links are enough. We only move answers when merging, and only when especially good or especially many answers need to be kept all together. The answers here are fully covered by the answers there, so leaving it here on the duplicate (assuming it gets closed as a duplicate) is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to grow a giant you must plant 2x2 square of saplings (and feed them bonemeal if you want it fast).

Quoting [Wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree)

> In order to grow a 2x2 jungle tree, four jungle saplings must be placed adjacent to each other. For growth to succeed, there may be no blocks adjacent (even diagonally) to the north-western sapling (which is considered the center of the tree) up to the final height of the tree, as well as no blocks 1 block away except at the same level of the sapling (even diagonally). Which sapling the Bone Meal is used on is irrelevant. Large jungle trees can grow up to 32 blocks high; trees as short as 9 blocks have also been observed.

(understand that the ivy that grows on the tree is "outside", that means it occupies 4x4 space outside the 2x2 trunk, so to grow the tree at the bottom of a pit you need a 4x4 pit.)

Next, the trees don't grow cocoa. They serve as soil for cocoa plants. Place a block of Jungle Wood, plant 4 cocoa seeds on its 4 sides and they will grow into mature cocoa plants.

And last but not least - it may be hard to make your farm self-sustainable. Supposedly one jungle giant drops less than 4 jungle tree saplings on the average...

Answer (score 1):

To make a tall tree plant 4 saplings in a 2x2 square. Then place bone meal on one of them to get a tall tree. Here is a video on how to do it.

[Tall Trees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q00uXoUMCdk)

Answer (score 1):

to get cocoa you need to put some cocoa on the jungle wood (which creates a small pod) and let it grow (or bonemeal it) which doubles or triples the cocoa

[the MC wiki has more information on farming cocoa](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cocoa#Farming)